# Calculate $\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} e^{iz}/z dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, complex-integration

> Let $C_R$ be the lower semicircle of radius $R$. Calculate
> $$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz$$

Does the following make sense? Expand $e^{iz}$ as its taylor series and observe that

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz =\lim_{R\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{C_R} \frac{{iz}^{n-1}}{n!}  $$

All of the terms besides $n=1$ have a primitive and so we need only calculate:

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{1}{z} dz$$

We will make a brach cut of $\log z$ on the imaginary axis so that if $z$ is in this region, then $\log z = \log |z| + i\arg z$ where $\arg z \in (\pi/2,5\pi/2)$. Thus,

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{1}{z} dz = \lim_{R\to \infty} \log z|_{Re^{i\pi}}^{Re^{2\pi i}} = \lim_{R\to \infty} \log R + 2\pi i - (\log R + \pi i) = \pi i $$

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why are the other integrals zero? we are on a semicircle and only even powers integrate to zero $dz$

Comment: Oh yes, the curve is not closed. Let me fix.

Comment: @Conrad, wouldn't the odd powers also integrate to zero?

Comment: sorry, it's the other way around - even powers do not integrate to zero ($dz$ is odd so odd power times $dz$ is even hence it is same as on the upper circle, so since sum is zero, result is zero) $\int_{C_r}z^{2k}dz=\int_{-\pi}^0r^{2k}e^{i2kt}ire^{it}dt=2ir^{2k+1}/(2k+1)$

Comment: A couple minor corrections to your post: first you need $\dfrac {i^nz^{n-1}}{n!}$. The $i$ is also raised to powers (even though it just cycles through 4 values). And second, the branch cut is the *upper* imaginary axis, not the whole axis (upper, so that $\log$ will be well behaved on $C_R$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi(t) = Re^{it}$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int_{C_R} \dfrac {e^{iz}}z\,dz &= \int_\pi^{2\pi}\dfrac{e^{i\phi(t)}}{\phi(t)} \phi'(t)\,dt
\\&=\int_\pi^{2\pi} \dfrac{e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}} iRe^{it}\,dt 
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{i^{n+1}R^n}{n!}\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{iRnt}\,dt
\end{align}$$